# Haskell Cabal QuickCheck Integration

Tags: haskell, cabal-install

I've been trying to use cabal-install as a way to build and, more importantly, test my haskell projects, a bit alike to the way Maven is used in Java projects, mainly because it seems to be  a good way as well to integrate in Jenkins or a ci or so, and it seems to be very reliable in a sense that you don't need a development environment and so on set up to check and confirm whether code is compiling and correct or not.

Anyways, I'm using QuickCheck and HUnit for this. In another post  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874601/how-to-use-hunit-and-cabal-to-do-automated-testing) on stack exchange I found a nice way to integrate HUnit and cabal, by using the function test in Distribution.TestSuite.HUnit to create an exposed tests array in my test module. Works.

I tried to do the same style of set up with quickcheck,

```
    import qualified Distribution.TestSuite.QuickCheck2 as CabalQuickCheck

    alwaysFalseOneArg::Int->(Int,Int)
    alwaysFalseOneArg x = (x,x)

    quickCheckPropOneArg = \s->let (a,b)=alwaysFalseOneArg s  in a==b && a/=b

    cabalQCTest = CabalQuickCheck.test "test" quickCheckPropOneArg

    tests=cabalQCTest:[]
```

I want to see this test fail.

The  cabal file I have works with the HUnit set up, with HUnit tests running and failing or not failing as they should. If I use the same set up to perform quickcheck tests however, cabal tells me that it indeed found a test suite, but there are no tests in it. I tried the approach that is mentioned on the [site](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.4/html/libraries/Cabal/Distribution-TestSuite.html) of Distribution.TestSuite.QuickCheck2 as well, but there they don't seem to mention how to expose the test and I don't seem to manage to make that run. I'm a bit at a loss now, I can run those quickcheck tests with quickcheck itself but not with cabal and I would like to have this to be able to quickly verify all my tests and code and use it in a Jenkins or so. Anybody an idea?

I tried to give all the info that I think is necessary without over-complicating stuff so I didn't post the complete cabal file and so on, if that would be necessary, I of course will do so. I found quite a few similar posts, but most of them boil down to using something else than detailed-0.9 which would be a pity as it seems to work quite nicely with HUnit as a set up and I would like to use both HUnit and QuickCheck in the same way of course, preferrably exposing one tests array containing HUnit and QuickCheck tests alike.

Kasper

Comment: Here is a possible example:
https://github.com/patperry/hs-monte-carlo/blob/master/monte-carlo.cabal
and a test with main calling QC:
https://github.com/patperry/hs-monte-carlo/blob/master/tests/Main.hs

Comment: Following up on gliptak's comment--I would investigate using test-framework; I find it somewhat more convenient. An [additional](https://github.com/isturdy/q/blob/master/tests/Tests.hs) [example](https://github.com/isturdy/q/blob/master/tests/Data/Queue/RealtimeTests.hs).

Answer (score 3):

I agree with [isturdy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1839894/isturdy): I would definitely have a go at `test-framework` + `test-framework-quickcheck2`. Check out [this example](https://github.com/fatuhoku/haskell-minecraft-tool/blob/master/test/TestMain.hs) of how to use them together in a project. Notice the properties called `prop_*`.

You can also check out the project `haskell-minecraft-tool` to see what the test output looks like. Run the tests with

```
cabal configure --enable-tests && cabal build && cabal test
```

Look at the `.cabal` file here to see what packages are required. Namely these are    `test-framework`, `test-framework-quickcheck2`, `QuickCheck`.